# Failed to parse error response, Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, rx-android

I have this type of error response

```
{
    "success": false,
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Validation Error.",
    "data": {
        "mobile": [
            "The mobile has already been taken."
        ]
    }
}
```

this is my pojo class

```
class LoginResponse
{
    @SerializedName ("success") var isSuccess = false
    @SerializedName ("code")var responseCode = 0
    @SerializedName ("message")lateinit var message : String
}
```

and this is my method

```
fun registration()
    {
        repository.registration()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(object : SingleObserver<LoginResponse> {
                override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {}

                override fun onSuccess(response: LoginResponse) {
                    Log.d("responseMsg", "success msg: ${response.message}")
                }

                override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                    Log.d("responseMsg", e.toString())
                    try {
                        val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
                        val body = (e as HttpException).response()!!.errorBody()
                        Log.d("responseMsg", "msg: ${body.toString()}")
                        val response = gson.fromJson(body.toString(), LoginResponse::class.java)
                        Log.d("responseMsg", "msg: ${response.message}")
                    }catch (ex : Exception)
                    {
                        Log.d("responseMsg", ex.toString())
                    }
                }
            })
    }
```

Trying in many ways, I can't find the problem. I also saw some solutions, still not working. please Someone help me, to find where is the problem?

Every time i got this error

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
```

Comment: What does `Log.d("responseMsg"` give you?

Comment: responseMsg: `retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.HttpException: HTTP 400 Bad Request`

responseMsg: msg: `okhttp3.ResponseBody$Companion$asResponseBody$1@4a3874`

responseMsg: `com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $`

Comment: None of those look like JSON.

Comment: what is my mistake ??

Comment: 1) call `ResponseBody.body().string()` not `toString`. 2) as is made clear in the docs you **must** close the response body. https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/index.html?okhttp3/ResponseBody.html